# how to check if a string contains a substring from an array of strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm still learning JavaScript but I just can't seem to find a way to see if a string contains a substring.

Basically I have some Titles of some individuals and I want to see if the Title contains strings like "President" or "Sr" in the title this is what i have so far but does not seem to be working.

```
var title = "President of Sales";
var arrayOfTitles = ["President","Chief","VP","SVP","Director","Manager","Mrg","Sr","Senior","Executive Assistant","Principle Architect","GM","Technical Advisor"];

var re = new RegExp(arrayOfTitles.join("|"),"i");

for(i = 0; i < arrayOfTitles.length; i++){
        if ( re.test(gr.title)){
            return; 
                }
     }
```

However this code will not work with String likes "Jr VP" or "President of Sales". Is there a way to build an array of Regex of these strings?

any help would be great thanks

Comment: You are looking for exact matches, so don't use regex, use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). If you want a case-insensitive search, apply toLowerCase on string and keywords. And, unless the above is in a function context, `return` doesn't make much sense there. Use `break` to leave the loop, and set a flag beforehand if you're interested in the positive or negative outcome of the whole test.

Comment: Using a single regex built from the `arrayOfTitles` should work, but if you do that you don't need to loop over the same array. Try `re.test(title)` *without* the loop - that worked fine for me.

Comment: Im looking for something that will match anything with these keywords in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run a loop

```js
var title = "President of Sales";
var arrayOfTitles = ["President","Chief","VP","SVP","Director","Manager","Mrg","Sr","Senior","Executive Assistant","Principle Architect","GM","Technical Advisor"];

var regex = new RegExp(arrayOfTitles.join("|"), "i");
//The regex will return true if found in the array
if ( regex.test(title) ){
  console.log("has");
}
```

Comment: Will this work for any String that contains on of the Strings in the Array?

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple like :

```js
var title = "President of Sales";
var arrayOfTitles = ["President","Chief","VP","SVP","Director","Manager","Mrg","Sr","Senior","Executive Assistant","Principle Architect","GM","Technical Advisor"];
var matches = (function() {
  for(var i=0; i < arrayOfTitles.length; i++) {
 if(title.indexOf(arrayOfTitles[i]) > -1) { return true; }
  }
  return false;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the includes() function, instead of indexOf().

```
     var title = "President of Sales";
       var arrayOfTitles = ["President","Chief","VP","SVP","Director","Manager","Mrg","Sr","Senior","Executive Assistant","Principle Architect","GM","Technical Advisor"];
       var matches = (function() {
         for(var i=0; i < arrayOfTitles.length; i++) {
               if(title.includes(arrayOfTitles[i])) { return true; }
         }
         return false;
       }());
```